# VBA: Creating different formatting for Error Bars in a Scatter Chart

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I'm trying to create a project timeline using vba. I want to create different color/style formatting for the vertical(Y) and horizontal(X) Error Bars. I used Record Macro first to see how the X and Y bars are selected differently, but both show as the same ErrorBars property. I want the Y Error bars to be dashed, but when I add that line of code both the X and Y Error bars are changed. Any suggestions?

```
Sub Timeline()

Dim sheet1 As Worksheet 
Dim timeline As Chart

Set sheet1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1") 
Set timeline = sheet1.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

With timeline

  .ChartType = xlXYScatter
  .SeriesCollection.NewSeries 
  .SeriesCollection(1).Name ="Project Lengths" 
  .SeriesCollection(1).XValues ="='sheet1'!C7:C25" 
  .SeriesCollection(1).Values ="='sheet1'!D7:D25" 

  .SeriesCollection(1).ErrorBar Direction:=xlX, Include:= _ 
      xlPlusValues, Type:=xlCustom, Amount:="='sheet1'!E7:E25"
  .SeriesCollection(1).ErrorBars.EndStyle = xlNoCap 
  .SeriesCollection(1).ErrorBars.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue  
  .SeriesCollection(1).ErrorBars.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 112, 192) 
  .SeriesCollection(1).ErrorBars.Format.Line.Transparency = 0 
  .SeriesCollection(1).ErrorBars.Format.Line.Weight = 2.5 

  .SeriesCollection(1).ErrorBar Direction:=xlY, Include:= _ 
      xlMinusValues, Type:=xlPercent, Amount:=100
  .SeriesCollection(1).ErrorBars.EndStyle = xlNoCap 
  .SeriesCollection(1).ErrorBars.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue 
  .SeriesCollection(1).ErrorBars.Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSysDash 

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting question, seems you can set different formats manually but the macro recorder doesn't show how to select each one.  It also appears Microsoft has made it available as `xlYErrorBars` and `xlXErrorBars` for the interop class... so why didn't they make it more available within excel? hmm...

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Excel are you using?
I just tried your code in Excel 2013 and it seems to work.

[image]

The horizontal error bars are in blue and dashed, the vertical error bars are in black and unbroken. It's a bit confusing because it looks like a bar diagram with really thin bars and horizontal error bars, but it works (at least in Excel 2013).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Above code also works for me (Excel 2013)
Upon trying to incorporate the solution in my code, the game changer was deleting the "Series.HasErrorBars = True" line.